# How I can reuse aiohttp.ClientSession?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I am building own async python package and faced the problem.

This is my code:

```python
class Client:
    """
    Async client for making requests
    """

    def __init__(self, base_url: str = BASE_URL) -> None:
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.session = ClientSession()

    async def get(self, method: str, *args: tp.Any, **kwargs: tp.Any) -> tp.Any:
        async with self.session.get(f'{self.base_url}/{method}', *args, **kwargs) as response:
            data = await response.json()
            return data
```

When I try to use something like this:

```python
await client.get()
```

I get

`RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`

I suppose that the reason of this error is calling `ClientSession()` not inside the coroutine. But I hope that somebody knows the way to re-use `ClientSession()`

I have already read other similar questions, but they are not suitable to my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize (and cache) the session when needed:

```py
class Client:
    """
    Async client for making requests
    """

    def __init__(self, base_url: str = BASE_URL) -> None:
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.session = None

    async def get(self, method: str, *args: tp.Any, **kwargs: tp.Any) -> tp.Any:
        if not self.session:
            self.session = ClientSession()
        async with self.session.get(f'{self.base_url}/{method}', *args, **kwargs) as response:
            data = await response.json()
            return data
```

Depending on how you use the `Client` you can also use a **class** attribute for the session object.

**Update**:

`ClientSession` creation should be protected from race condition using Mutex:

```py
_session_mutex = asyncio.Lock()

async def __create_session_if_required(self):
    if self.session is None:
        async with self._session_mutex:
            if self.session is None:
                self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
                # should be closed if not Singleton class: "await session.close()"

async def get(..):
    await self.__create_session_if_required()
    async with self.session.get() as response:
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue a little while ago. I tried storing the `aiohttp.ClientSession` in the **init** function, but whenever I tried to use it, I got `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`.

This is OK, but the trick is to do it right. The `aiohttp.ClientSession` must be initialized inside a task, meaning an async function. The **init** function is not async, however it is still OK, as long as any parent function is async. Let me clarify with some code snippets.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def make_http_get_request(self, url: str) -> str:
        async with self._session.request("GET", url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return await response.text()


def main() -> None:
    my_class = MyClass()
    html = asyncio.run(my_class.make_http_get_request("http://github.com/"))
    print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code will result in a `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` because the `MyClass`, and it's `aiohttp.ClientSession` is initialized outside of a task. The correct way would be:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def make_http_get_request(self, url: str) -> str:
        async with self._session.request("GET", url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return await response.text()


async def main() -> None:
    my_class = MyClass()  # This is now being initilized inside a task (async function)
    html = await my_class.make_http_get_request("http://github.com/")
    print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Of course, you will still get some warnings like `Unclosed client session` and `Unclosed connector` with code like this, because you are not closing your resources properly. Let's write better code to take care of that:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def close(self) -> None:
        await self._session.close()

    async def make_http_get_request(self, url: str) -> str:
        async with self._session.request("GET", url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return await response.text()


async def main() -> None:
    my_class = MyClass()
    html = await my_class.make_http_get_request("http://github.com/")
    print(html)

    await my_class.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

However, this would still leave us with these pesky warnings if we for some reason crash, due to some unforeseen exception. We can make this better yet, using context managers:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from traceback import TracebackException
from types import TracebackType


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "MyClass":
        return self

    async def __aexit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Exception,
        exc_val: TracebackException,
        traceback: TracebackType,
    ) -> None:
        await self.close()

    async def close(self) -> None:
        await self._session.close()

    async def make_http_get_request(self, url: str) -> str:
        async with self._session.request("GET", url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return await response.text()


async def main() -> None:
    async with MyClass() as my_class:
        html = await my_class.make_http_get_request("http://github.com/")
        print(html)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I hope this clears things up.